# Some doubts about how to retrieve multiple IP addresses (if I have more than one network card) in Java?

Tags: java, networking, ip-address

I have the following  2 problems in retrieving the ip of a client.

I have create the following code inside a class:

```
private static InetAddress thisIp;

static{
    try {
        thisIp  = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("MyIp is: " + thisIp);
    } catch(UnknownHostException ex) {

    }
}
```

My problems are:

1) The previous code should retrieve the IP address of a client, when I execute it it print the following message:

**MyIp is: andrea-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1**

Why it begin with **andrea-virtual-machine/** ? (I am developing on a virtual machine), is it a problem?

2) In this way I can retrieve only a single IP address but I could have more than a single network card so I could have more than a single IP address but **multiple IP addresses**

What can I do to handle this situation? I want put all the **multiple IP addresses** into an ArrayList

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No, it's not a problem, it's simply an output that consists of hostname and IP (`hostname/ip`). A detail that you might want to read up: The method `toString()` in the class `InetAddress` is implemented to return this format.
2. The following code will list all IP addresses for each of the interfaces in your system (and also stores them in a list that you could then pass on etc...):

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException
   {
       List<String> allIps = new ArrayList<String>();
       Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
       while (e.hasMoreElements())
       {
           NetworkInterface n = e.nextElement();
           System.out.println(n.getName());
           Enumeration<InetAddress> ee = n.getInetAddresses();
           while (ee.hasMoreElements())
           {
               InetAddress i = ee.nextElement();
               System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());
               allIps.add(i.getHostAddress());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The method `boolean isLoopbackAddress()` allows you to filter the potentially unwanted loopback addresses.

The returned `InetAddress` is either a `Inet4Address` or a `Inet6Address`, using the `instanceof` you can figure out if the returned IP is IPv4 or IPv6 format.

Comment: Tnx, but I have a last doubt about your code: I have insert into it 2 println that simply print the size of the allIps list and its content and I obtain this message: List of all IP on this client: [fe80:0:0:0:20c:29ff:fe15:3dfe%2, 192.168.15.135, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, 127.0.0.1]
Number of ip: 4
So why this list contain 4 IPs? I have only one network card...what represents the other ips?

Comment: yes, these are the 4 IP addresses of your system, two of them are in IPv4 format, two of them in IPv6 format. One of each is the localhost interface, the other one, is the one connected to the network.

Comment: mmm I think that this is not good for me, I need only the list of all the "classic" IP which interact with the server, in my case the list have to contain only the 192.168.15.135, and if I have more than one network card the IP adress list have to contain only the adresses having this form...what can I do?

Comment: I updated my answer with the two methods that will help you achieve this.

Comment: Ok...I have understand how to use isLoopbackAddress() method to exlude the loopback address but it seems to me that the InetAddress don't provide the getFamily() method of which you speak about...are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

if your system is configured with multiple ip then do like this.

```
try {
  InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  InetAddress[] ips = InetAddress.getAllByName(inet.getCanonicalHostName());
  if (ips  != null ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(ips[i]);
    }
  }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hostname listed before the IP, incidentally, is part of INetAddress. You get both the name and the address because you didn't try to show only the address.